How do I send an email from within this apps script function?
I followed this https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet setting up my website.
ALL I WANT is to send an email to my gmail whenever it runs the function
The function in my google apps script:
function doPost (e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.stack)
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
 
}

I tried incorporating this function after .setvalues as 'sendEmail()' and just embedded in the code there but it wouldn't work!!!
function sendEmail() {
  var recipient = "MY EMAIL";
  var subject = "Check out Apps Script";
  var body = "I just discovered Apps Script and it's so cool!";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}


Have you checked the Google Apps Script execution logs in your Google Apps Script editor console? Can you check if you see any errors?

I found the answer - this uses a web app, so it needed a new version of the deployment. Fixed by (in the apps script editor) clicking deploy -> manage deployments -> edit (pencil icon) -> version -> new version
